# be born + adjective

Tags: grammar

I've read this sentence:

```
Some people are born brainy.
```

here: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/born

Actually I was forming a sentence that describes that a man's been good and holy right from the time he was born. I took help from this sentence but one thing that I need to discuss is that 'be born' is followed by an Adjective, can we put a NOUN in this?

Which one is better?

> He was born holy.
>
> He was born as a holy man.

Comment: We would normally say a 'he was a born holy man'.

Comment: Well, he obviously wasn't born as a man! You could try 'born to be...'.

Comment: So which is the right one b/w the two you two have described?